# Why react native command not working and show error?

Tags: react-native

in react native , when I want to use react native vector icons .   but showing this error.

```
 $ react-native link
error: unknown command 'link'
```

`$ react-native link

success

`

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of React-Naitve (**>0.69**) link command is deleted. You can use react-native-assets instead of link command.

You can follow the instructions in this link, to setup react-native-vector-icons in your project:
[react-native-vector-icons-fonts-react-native-app-ui](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-native-vector-icons-fonts-react-native-app-ui/)

Comment: New documentation react native remove this ....  I  am just learning RN.